# How to cancel the training process (`EstimatorChain<TLastTransformer>.Fit` method) in `ML.NET`?

Tags: c#, ml.net

Is it possible to cancel the training in `ML.NET`?

If it is not available directly, are there any workarounds?

Also, not interested in `AutoML`.